# to find variable within a variable

Tags: variables, tcl

I am trying to use tcl command to find a variable value within a variable, but couldn't get the correct value to it. the code is as shown below. still a newbie to tcl.

```
set Q 8 
set W 5
set acell_$Q$W ""
foreach_in_collection a $A {
echo "$acell_($Q$W)"
set Q [expr $Q+1]
set W [expr $W+2]
lappend acell_$Q$w $a
echo "new cell added on new $Q$W is $acell_($Q$W)"
}
```

the 1st echo result should return blank.
and the end echo new cell result should show "new cell added on new 97 is "

Comment: Why did you call your variable `acell_$Q$W` first when it seems you actually needed it to be named `acell_($Q$W)`? Also variable names are case sensitive. `$w` is not the same as `$W`.

Comment: There seems to be inconsistency in variable naming. Sometimes one thing, sometimes another. _That won't work, in almost all programming languages,_ and Tcl is one of those languages. Also, standard Tcl would use `puts` instead of `echo`…